# How should the lifecycle of MongoClient work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.Net MVC application using MongoDB as the database. The website and the database are on separate servers.

At the moment, I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Mongo
{
    private IMongoDatabase database;

    public Mongo()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@ipaddress:port");
        database = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
    }

    public IMongoCollection<ApplicationUser> Users() { return database.GetCollection<ApplicationUser>("Users"); }
}
```

So to use it... (essentially in every request)

```
Mongo mon = new Mongo();
mon.Users.Find(........); // etc.
```

And this works ok - most of the time.  On the odd occasion things appear to lock up and the database just times out until I restart the website.  I get timeout errors where it's trying to connect to the database server.

While that's going on, the database server is confirmed up, and I'm able to connect to MongoDB from another mongo client without issue.

I'm conscious that there's no "close connection" thing going on in this - but there doesn't appear to be one to even call.  So I wonder if it's something to do with too many connections being open and not being cleaned up properly.

Am I using MongoClient incorrectly?  Is there something obvious that I should be doing to stop these timeouts?

This is the trace of the error I get:

```
   [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ipaddress:port]
       System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6768957
       System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) +57
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
       MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.<ConnectAsync>d__7.MoveNext() +1542
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
       MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.<CreateStreamAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +345
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
       MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.<OpenAsyncHelper>d__1.MoveNext() +553

[MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.]
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.<OpenAsyncHelper>d__1.MoveNext() +1372
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.<GetChannelAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +548
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +639
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   MongoDB.Driver.<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() +272
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   MongoDB.Driver.<ExecuteReadOperation>d__35`1.MoveNext() +396
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   MongoDB.Driver.<ToListAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext() +294
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are using `MongoClient` incorrectly. As indicated in [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/connecting/#re-use)

> It is recommended to store a `MongoClient` instance in a global place,
>   either as a static variable or in an IoC container with a singleton
>   lifetime.

So you should rework your code to create a singleton `MongoClient` instance and then use that throughout your program.

The reason is that `MongoClient` maintains a pool of open connections that can be shared and reused for best performance.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve the connection issue, although does answer the question thanks.  The docs say that it's recommended but you can create multiple instances as behind the scenes it will still use connection pooling as long as the connection strings are the same

Comment: @Paul Keep Reading! `Unfortunately, certain types of settings are not able to be compared for equality. For instance, the ClusterConfigurator property is a delegate and only its address is known for comparison. If you wish to construct multiple MongoClients, ensure that your delegates are all using the same address if the intent is to share connection pools.`